# Text box added using javascript doesnot respond as expected to the js attached to it

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am adding a text box using javascript:

This is what is generated:

```
       <dd id="text3-element" style="width: 350px;">
            <input type="text" size="50" id="text3" name="text3" onblur="return getFieldValue(this.id);" value="">
       </dd>
```

This is what is present in the getFieldValue function:

```
            function getFieldValue(id){

                var elem = document.getElementById(id);
                alert(elem.value);
                return false;
            }
```

I'm trying to get the value of the field added using javascript when the value of the filed changes.

However, I keep getting the value as 'undefined', in spite of entering text into the newly added text box.

This does not happen if the form already has a text box to begin with - i.e., if a text box is not being added via a js function.

Anything missing / look wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding the input-box? With document.write() or through the DOM ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'adding the ?' but im creating an input element and adding it as a child node to the parent div.

Comment: oh spoke too soon :) i see you just edited your comment

Comment: Is it possible that your code has added *multiple* elements like that, all with the same "id" value?  That's a no-no.

Comment: @Mallika Iyer: Yup, G-forsaken strip-tags functionality :P

Comment: Pointy might have a.. point.. there - Ok, cheap one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the functional requirement, but why don't you just pass the element itself through the function?

```
<input type="text" onblur="return getFieldValue(this);">
```

with

```
function getFieldValue(element){
    alert(element.value);
    return false;
}
```

This should work fine.

Comment: was just typing that in ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me on both IE and Chrome. Maybe some other part of the script that you have not posted is throwing the error, can you post the javascript you're using to add the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt catch if there is no value set for the input

```
function getFieldValue(element)
{
if (element.value =="") {
    alert("Please enter something");
    return false;
  }
else
{
// make something else
}
}

Test 

<input type="text" onblur="return getFieldValue(this);">
```

Comment: thanks...didnt need this...im populating an array and filtering out the null/empty values anyway.